# Comment écrire le symbole « non prononcé » en phonétique ?

Tags: phonétique

Par exemple, le « s » de « nous » ne se prononce pas, « nous » se prononce /nu/.

Y a-t-il un phonème pour indiquer le son **non prononcé** (/s/) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il me semble qu'il y a une contradiction dans les termes...

La phonétique (pour simplifier, bien sûr, je ne me prétends pas linguiste), c'est précisément se baser sur ce qu'on entend, et non sur ce qu'on lit. Quel besoin aurait-on de représenter en phonétique des lettres qui sont muettes ?

Quand une *lettre écrite* n'est pas prononcée, elle est simplement ignorée dans sa transcription phonétique, que tu as bien écrite :

> "nous" (français)  →  /nu/ (phonétique)

Comment: tu as razón. merci pour ta réponse